# How to write file paths to a txt file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file

I'm trying to multiple lines to a text file in Python

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("open\n" +
                  "c:\files\file.scr"+
                  "close"
                 )
```

The file  path isn't written correctly,

```
   open
    c:iles\drawing.dwgclose
```

Could someone suggest how to write the file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the string `raw` by adding `r` in front:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("open\n" +
                  r"c:\files\file.scr"+
                  "close"
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to escape \ in strings

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("open\n" +
                  "c:\\files\\file.scr"+
                  "close"
                 )
```